# How to add a card widget dynamically whenever floating action button is clicked in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am very new to flutter and was just curious to know how can we create a new card widget everytime a button (lets say FAB) is clicked.

Suppose this is the card widget :

```
return Card(
 child: Column(
  children: [
  Text('name'),
  Text('standard'),
  Text('Roll No'),
    ],
   ),
 );
```

I want the cards to build with the same content everytime the FAB is clicked. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: You need to check about ‘listsview’ state full widget and set state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First declare a List of widget type

```
List<Widget> _cardList = [];
```

Then create your widget which you want to add on button click, e.g.

```
  Widget _card() {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('name'),
          Text('standard'),
          Text('Roll No'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

add your widget in List on button click

```
FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _cardList.add(_card());
              });
            },
          ),
```

Now use a `ListView.builder` for create a list of widget

```
 ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: _cardList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _cardList[index];
      },
    )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Any idea regarding how can we remove the cards that we want ?

Comment: just use remove method of array like this ` _cards.removeAt(index)`

Comment: I got your idea but here the problem is that the card widget is defined outside the class. So, setState() can't be used. I had given a cancel icon at the right of the card but i can't use the cardList because it is not defined here. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You have index of every item in list view, just store whatever index you want to remove in separate variable and use this index in removeAt parameter.